# How to clear whole navigation history hosted by the Windoes8 Frame control?

Tags: windows-8

I want to clear the frame's history.But I could'nt find such method or property in Frame Class API.Please help me !

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do exactly this. I just performed the same steps in the app.cs to create a fresh frame with no history (assuming you're using the templates).

```
Frame rootFrame = new Frame();
SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "AppFrame");
Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyAwesomePage)))
{
     throw new Exception("Failed to restart navigation :(");
}
```

Comment: changing frame is one of the answer of this question ! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be a very wise idea. If you're using the Navigation  Service, you would have no need to clear the history of it. Doing this could cause you to fail Windows Store certification, as it would seem to suggest that you're doing something to alter the way the user would expect to navigate in the application, which, in my experience, is a big no-no with these apps. But I could be wrong. Could you provide some more context?

Comment: Thank you message.My apps has snap view.And the snap view's function is global menu of the apps(like tab).When user transition to pages from the snap view,the page display back button to go back the frame'record.If the back button pushed,The snap page will show.It is unnatural.so I wanted to clear the record of the frame.Finally,I solved this trouble by hide the back button.